# Text-Overflow over multiple cells: Howto ignore text with Hover etc..?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Table (see sample attached), where a text may overflow over some cells.
"11:00 - 13:30 " in my example is the text of the first pink cell, with style "overflow: visible". That is on purpose. So far so good, but now my text triggers hover and clicks always for the first cell: Say you move your mouse over "13:30" I need hover triggered for the underlying = second cell.

Is there a way to kind of "ignore" the text as an element, and pass all events & hover to the next element (= cells) ?

[image: Table Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the click event is on the cell, you can unbind the mouse events of the text from css, e.:

```
.cell p { pointer-events: none;}
```

Comment: yeah sure, but i had to wait till SO allows me to do so